# Formatting JavaScript code embedded in a cshtml file

Tags: visual-studio, code-formatting

Is it possible to format the JavaScript code embedded in a `.cshtml` file using the Visual Studio editor?

I tried the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keyboard shortcut, and also the "Format Selection" option in the context menu. However, neither of these seem to work on JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just searched and found the [**PrettyJs** plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/41a0cc2f-eefd-4342-9fa9-3626855ca22a). I do understand that there might be other plugins that do the same thing, but this works perfectly well for me.

With this plugin, you can format your JavaScript code either as a document or by selection. Both can be done using the shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, respectively.